# How to style Dialog with className property from styling sheet in mui5 using Emotion/styled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I try to style mui Dialog but it doesnt acceppt className even inside PaperProps. Inline styles are working but I would like to import styles from styling sheet called Styles

```
 <Styles>
      <div>       
    {dialogOpen ? (
      <Dialog
        className="dialog"
        onClose={() => setDialogOpen(false)}
        open={dialogOpen}
        PaperProps={{
          className="paper"
        }}
      >
        <DialogTitle className="title">TITLE</DialogTitle>
      </Dialog>
    ) : null}
  </div>
</Styles>
```

And this is styling file

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material";

const Styles = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  "& .text": {
  backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  "& .dialog": {
   backgroundColor: "green",
 },
  "& .text": {
  color: "yellow",
  },
}));

export { Styles };
```

Comment: I think You need to import useStyles function from MUI and use it

Comment: useStyles is deprecated in mui5

Answer (score 0):

To style a Material-UI `Dialog` component using the `className` property with styles defined in a separate stylesheet, you can use the `makeStyles` function provided by Material-UI. Here's how you can do it:

First, create a separate stylesheet (e.g., `Styles.js`) to define your styles:

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const Styles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  dialog: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
  },
  paper: {
    // Customize paper styles here
  },
  title: {
    // Customize title styles here
  },
}));

export default Styles;
```

Now, import the `Styles` function into your component and apply the styles to your `Dialog` component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import Styles from "./Styles"; // Import your styles

function MyComponent() {
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const classes = Styles(); // Initialize your styles

  return (
    <div>
      {dialogOpen ? (
        <Dialog
          className={classes.dialog} // Apply the dialog style
          onClose={() => setDialogOpen(false)}
          open={dialogOpen}
          PaperProps={{
            className: classes.paper, // Apply the paper style
          }}
        >
          <DialogTitle className={classes.title}>TITLE</DialogTitle> {/* Apply the title style */}
        </Dialog>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

In this code, we import the `Styles` function from your separate stylesheet and initialize it within your component. Then, we apply the generated class names to the corresponding components within your `Dialog` component.

Make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed to use the `makeStyles` function and that you've set up your project to work with MUI version 5 or later, as the code provided is based on that version.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however makeStyles and useStyles are not recommended in Mui5 , they introduced a new styling engine called "styled" which is little different

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

const Styles = {
  Dialog: styled("div")({
    "& .paper": {
      backgroundColor: "green",
    },
    "& .title": {
      // Customize title styles here
    },
  }),
};

export default Styles;
```

Now, import the Styles object into your component and apply the styles to your Dialog component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import Styles from "./Styles"; // Import your styles

function MyComponent() {
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {dialogOpen ? (
        <Styles.Dialog>
          <Dialog
            className="paper"
            onClose={() => setDialogOpen(false)}
            open={dialogOpen}
          >
            <DialogTitle className="title">TITLE</DialogTitle>
          </Dialog>
        </Styles.Dialog>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```